# exit ruby without raise an error, like in php?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, exit, raise

I need to use exit in ruby. But my problem is "exit" method raise an error :

> SystemExit in ...

I want like in php show all the view until the exit instruction. How can I do that?

Comment: Not "all" PHP is like that.

Comment: @NabilKadimi what do you mean? if I write "exit('toto')" evrywhere in  PHP code, I will have execution of all previous code, and all previous output + exit output at screen, and that all.

Comment: In an MVC PHP project, it's unliky that you'll put the exit; in a view.

Comment: I talk in "normal" php. You can stop when you want. I want to be abble to control that too in Ruby (and rails)